# jQuery Validate plugin with added custom methods and error messages

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Here's the link to [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/exciter/sfKks/25/).

Hello

I am learning the JQuery validator plugin and its API. I am almost there but cannot seem to find a solid example regarding the solution I like to implement. I have done a lot of online search and have found bits and pieces but nothing that explains this well.

I have a simple form with these fields:

- First Name
- Last Name
- E-mail
- Phone

Currently, these fields are being validated without any custom methods or error messages. So if the form is submitted with empty fields "required *" pops up.

What I would like to do is to validate a field beyond just checking if it is blank/empty or not. So for example with:

First Name:

1. Field is not blank/empty
2. Field does not contain alphanumeric characters

Phone:

1. Field is not blank/empty
2. Field only contain numeric characters

I am very new at implementing custom validator methods, I don't know how to display the correct error messages according. So if the phone field is not blank but container non numeric characters, I would like to flag it and show error message that this field only accepts numeric characters.

Currently, I have on error message "required *" within the message object of the validator and, I don't know how to implement error messages on granular level.

I apologies for such a long winded explanation. I would highly appreciate it if someone can point me into the right direction. Thank you

Here's the link to [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/exciter/sfKks/25/).

```
    <div class="wrapper">

        <form id="contactForm" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="fieldGroup">
           <!--  FIRST NAME --->     
               <lable for="firstname">First Name: </label>
               <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" size="25" maxlength="25" >
           </div>
            <!--  LAST NAME  -->   
            <div class="fieldGroup">
               <lable for="lastname">Last Name: </label>
               <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" size="25" maxlength="25" >  
            </div>  
            <!--  EMAIL  -->    
            <div class="fieldGroup">
               <lable for="email">Email: </label>
               <input type="text" id="email" name="email" size="25" maxlength="40" >     
            </div>   
            <!--  PHONE  -->    
            <div class="fieldGroup">
               <lable for="lastname">Phone: </label>
               <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" size="12" maxlength="12" >   
               xxx-xxx-xxxx
            </div>        

            <div class="fieldGroup">
               <input type="submit" id="SubmitBtn" value="Submit" >  
               <input type="reset" id="ResettBtn" value="Reset" >                
            </div>            

        </form>

    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    (function($,W,D)
    {
        var JQUERY4U = {};

        JQUERY4U.UTIL =
        {
            setupFormValidation: function()
            {
                //form validation rules
                $("#contactForm").validate({
                    rules: {
                        firstname: {
                            required: true,
                            chkData: true
                        },
                        lastname: {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 2,
                            maxlength: 15               
                        },
                        address1:{
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 8,
                            maxlength: 30               
                        },
                        city:{
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 8,
                            maxlength: 25           
                        },                  
                        state:{
                            required: true          
                        },
                        zipcode:{
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 5,
                            maxlength: 10   
                        },
                        phone: {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 10,
                            maxlength: 12                       
                        },
                        email:
                        {
                            required: true,
                            email: true
                        }                   
                    },
                    messages: {
                        firstname: "required *",
                        lastname: "required *",
                        address1: "required *",
                        city: "required *",
                        state: "required *",
                        zipcode: "required *",
                        phone: "required *",
                        email: "required *",
                    },
                    submitHandler: function(form) {
                        form.submit();
                    }
                });
            }


        }

        //when the dom has loaded setup form validation rules
        $(D).ready(function($) {

                $.validator.addMethod("chkData",
                function(value, element){
                    alert(value);
                },"SORRY");
            JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
        });

    })(jQuery, window, document);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was slightly more complicated than it needed to be.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#contactForm").validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                required: true,
                alphanumeric: true
            },
            lastname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2,
                maxlength: 15
            },
            address1: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8,
                maxlength: 30
            },
            city: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8,
                maxlength: 25
            },
            state: {
                required: true
            },
            zipcode: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                maxlength: 10
            },
            phone: {
                required: true,
                phoneUS: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            firstname: {
                required: "required *",
                alphanumeric: "custom alphanumeric message"
            },
            lastname: "required *",
            address1: "required *",
            city: "required *",
            state: "required *",
            zipcode: "required *",
            phone: "required *",
            email: "required *",
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/7uDXQ/**

**NOTES**:

**1)**  `alphanumeric` and `phoneUS` rules requires inclusion of the [`additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/additional-methods.js).

**2)**

> "Currently, I have on error message `required *` within the `messages`
>   object of the validator and, I don't know how to implement error
>   messages on granular level."

Custom messages are simply implemented as per a format similar to your `rules:`:

```
messages: {
    firstname: {
        required: "custom required *",
        alphanumeric: "custom alphanumeric message"
    },
}
```

Otherwise, if you only do this...

```
messages: {
    firstname: "custom required *",
}
```

Then **all** messages for **all** rules on the `firstname` field will share this same custom message.

**3)**  You do not have to specify the `submitHandler` callback function unless you need to do something on a valid form, like `ajax`.  Otherwise, by default, the form will simply do a normal `submit` on a valid form.  Compare the code in my jsFiddle to the code I posted above.

**4)**  There is no such rule as `chkData` so I removed it.  If this is your custom rule, then apply your custom message as per my item #2 above.

Comment: Thank you so much, Sparky. This absolutely helps a lot.